# Google's radarSearch searches in rectangular instead of circular area?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places

I use Google's *Radar Search* to get some markers from an area. I use a query likes this:

```
const location=new google.maps.LatLng(59.33, 18.0674);
const radius = 2000;

var request={
   location: location,
   radius: radius,
   types: ["bus_station"]
};
// ...
```

The problem is that the query returns results from a rectangular area rather than a circular area. To see that even clearer, I draw a circle:

```
var circOptions={
   center: location,
   radius: radius,
   map: map
};
circle = new google.maps.Circle(circOptions);
```

Here is my whole HTML code(including script & style):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false&language=se"></script>
   <script>

   function init() {

      const location=new google.maps.LatLng(59.33, 18.0674);
      const radius = 2000;

      // Make map
      var mapOptions = {
         center: location,
         zoom: 11,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

      // Make a circle
      var circOptions={
            center: location,
            radius: radius,
            map: map
      };
      circle = new google.maps.Circle(circOptions);  

      // Get shops in radius
      service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      var request={                                               //my request
         location: location,
         radius: radius,
         types: ["bus_station"]
      };
      service.radarSearch(request, function (results, status){
         if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK){
            for (var i= 0, result; result=results[i]; i++) {     //add markers
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: result.geometry.location,
                        reference: result.reference
               });
            }
         }
      });

   }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

   </script>
   <style>#map {height: 500px;width: 500px;}</style>
</head>
<body><div id="map"></div></body>
</html>
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't giving radius, give the results within a circular area and giving bounds give results for a rectangular area?

Answer (score 0):

A fast fix I found is to add

```
var distance=google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(location, result.geometry.location);
  if (distance>radius)
    continue;
```

Just under the `for` when making the markers. So it should look like this:

```
for (var i= 0, result; result=results[i]; i++) {     //add markers
   distance=google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(location, result.geometry.location);
   if (distance>radius)
      continue;
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: result.geometry.location,
      reference: result.reference
   });
}
```

Still not sure though of the reason for this weird behaviour.